# Xcode7 JSONString crash.In Xocde6 not

Tags: xcode7

used JsonKit

```
NSDictionary *json = [result.text objectFromJSONString];
NSString *config = [json JSONString];
```

Run in Xcode6 is no problem, but in Xcode7 running crash

Comment: Not enough information.

Answer (score 0):

This may be not issue of Xcode. but if you run project in 64 bit device it may crash . I have the same issue.

I replaced my jsonkit by the kit provided in this link:

https://github.com/heroims/JSONKit

and the problem solved.

Thanks